# JLabel not updating points scored

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to make a simple game in Greenfoot. I have everything else working good, but, it doesn't update the points.

```
int pointsScored = 0;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points Scored");
JLabel label = new JLabel("Points Scored " + pointsScored);

public void act() 
{
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    if (atWorldEdge()) {
       turn(180);
       pointsScored++;
       if (pointsScored != 0) {
           frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    move();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the text in a label you need to use:

```
pointsScored++;
label.setText( "Points Scored " + pointsScored );
```

Changing the value of a variable does not update any other expression where the variable was previously used.

Answer (score 0):

Update the JLabels text each time the score changes

```
pointsScored++;
label.setText("Points Scored: " + pointsScored);
```

Just updating the variable doesn't update the label